# Neural Network Data Normalization Setup

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, regression

I am fairly new to Neural Networks and have some questions regarding data normalization.

I am trying to build a regression neural network with two neurons on the output layer using a 'mean_squared_error' loss function. The problem I am running into is that one of the outputs is on a small scale (values within 0.9 to 1.4) and the other output is on a much larger scale (values within 60 to 80).

My understanding is that multiple output neurons use the following formula to calculate MSE

MSE = (|op1 - targ1|^2 + |op2 - targ2|^2 ) / 2

Given that the scales are off by an order of magnitude I believe I have to normalize the target columns of the training data-set before applying the neural network to make sure they are both weighted equally and scales don't influence the outcome.

I also read that ANN perform better when input data is normalized, so I went ahead and normalized all the data-set by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation (z-score normalization).

Here is the code I used to build the sequential model after the input normalization:

```
def build_model(n_layers, input_dim, units, activation):#, initializer):
    if isinstance(units, list):
        assert len(units) == n_layers
    else:
        units = [units] * n_layers


model = Sequential()

# Adds first hidden layer with input_dim parameter
model.add(Dense(units=units[0], 
                input_dim=input_dim, 
                activation=activation,
                kernel_regularizer=l2(0),
                #kernel_initializer=initializer, 
                name='h1'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())


# Adds remaining hidden layers
for i in range(2, n_layers + 1):
    model.add(Dense(units=units[i-1], 
                    activation=activation,
                    kernel_regularizer=l2(0),
                    #kernel_initializer=initializer, 
                    name='h{}'.format(i)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())


# Adds output layer
model.add(Dense(units=2,name='o'))#,kernel_initializer=initializer))

# Compiles the model

optimizer = Adam(lr= 0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8,
decay=0.05, amsgrad=False)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=optimizer,metrics=[coeff_determination])
return model
```

And here is how I compiled the model (10 layers, 50 hidden units per layer):

```
model = build_model(n_layers=10,input_dim=len(model_inputs),units=50,activation='relu')
```

I finally fitted my model using:

```
history = model.fit(x=X_norm, y=Y_norm, epochs=225, batch_size = X_norm.shape[0])
```

And got this output for the last epoch:

Epoch 225/225 162/162 [=======================] - 0s 86us/step - loss: 1.2539e-04

I went ahead and ran a prediction on the training data-set as a sanity check using:

```
Y_new = model.predict(X_new)
```

and finally I "de-normalized" the prediction using the mean and standard deviation used to normalized the target columns in the first place.

Here is how the actual vs prediction stacked up for a few observations:

Prediction:

```
    target_1    target_2
0   82.485733   1.370714
1   80.422562   1.260928
4   81.192978   1.216307
5   67.609528   1.191042
6   71.330009   1.012126
7   75.563698   1.161521
8   80.212601   1.341668
9   76.349266   0.962544
10  81.197662   1.307808
12  79.872147   1.306849
13  82.837700   1.313502
14  73.760750   1.687881
16  75.290382   1.368603
18  70.717682   1.229838
19  76.409767   1.307446
20  85.307167   1.342816
21  70.818542   1.242142
22  78.467438   1.382735
23  75.320892   1.238882
25  89.502998   1.446245
```

Actuals:

```
    target_1  target_2
0   86.2700   1.243
1   81.2960   1.330
4   75.2020   1.309
5   73.8390   1.342
6   73.1020   1.296
7   79.8180   0.795
8   77.3300   1.612
9   78.4010   1.074
10  65.6410   1.457
12  83.9160   1.449
13  69.1829   1.166
14  88.9450   1.056
16  77.7440   1.392
18  71.8940   1.169
19  86.0040   1.306
20  79.8420   1.215
21  74.3650   0.977
22  66.3840   1.464
23  84.3200   1.295
25  75.8870   1.808
```

[image]
[image]

Questions:

1. I feel that for such a low cost value the prediction and actual
   values should be a lot closer, especially for the training data-set,
   but maybe I am thinking about this the wrong way.
2. Is there any downside to normalizing the inputs and target columns ?
3. Am I carrying out the normalization correctly ?
4. Am I re-converting the outputs of the model correctly by using the
   mean and standard deviation used to normalize them in the first
   place ?
5. Is my setup valid for two neuron regression NN ?

Comment: Can you add an scatter / line plot of actual v/s predicted values for these two columns ?

Comment: Added the plots. Do I need to define a different cost function since I am dealing with two output neuron ?